# Native EclipseLink: enable second level cache for some entities

Tags: java, caching, eclipselink

In our project, the "old" native (non-JPA) version of EclipseLink is still in use. The mappings are configured using the Workbench Application (which generates XML configuration files and some Java code).

What we see in the workbench tool: it looks like for all entities the cache is enabled with isolation level Shared (default).

What we see in the application: no entity gets cached

What we want: Enable second level caching for some few entities only

**EDIT**

Config in EclipseLink Workbench:

[image]

Generated XML config:

```
  [...]
  <refresh-cache-policy/>
  <caching-policy/>
  [...]
```

Generated project code:

```
    // ClassDescriptor Properties.
    descriptor.useSoftCacheWeakIdentityMap();
    descriptor.setIdentityMapSize(100);
    descriptor.useRemoteSoftCacheWeakIdentityMap();
    descriptor.setRemoteIdentityMapSize(100);
    descriptor.setReadOnly();
    descriptor.setAlias("SomeAlias");

    // Cache Invalidation Policy
    TimeToLiveCacheInvalidationPolicy policy = new TimeToLiveCacheInvalidationPolicy(1000);
    policy.setShouldUpdateReadTimeOnUpdate(false);
    descriptor.setCacheInvalidationPolicy(policy);

    // Query Manager.
    descriptor.getQueryManager().checkCacheForDoesExist();
```

Comment: Not sure what you mean exactly by no entity gets cached if you set the default to use a shared cache.  Your code must be changing the cache level through some customizer or runtime call, as this is completely configurable at anytime at the project or descriptor level.

Comment: Still not enough info.  Since this is an existing app, was it always intended to use a cache and you are just now realizing it wasn't, or trying to change things?  How are you sure it isn't using a cache, and how are you using it? As mentioned, these project settings can be changed anytime in the application through the use of customizers and runtime calls, so you need to go through the application itself to figure out why thing might not be working as you expect.

Comment: I think it's some kind of default (all entities seem to have this configuration) and caching was not intended before for these entities. Now, for some read-only entities we would like to enable caching. We're noticing it doesn't use a cache since changes in db instantly effect the application.

Comment: Its not, though the TimeToLiveCacheInvalidationPolicy(1000) is stating objects built in the cache only have 1 second to live before they are invalidated.  Invalidation forces the next query for that data to rebuild it from the database and might be what you are seeing.  You haven't shown a specific example though, so I can't be sure.

Answer (score 0):

For now, our work-around is to use ehcache and Spring to cache method calls instead.

Once we can move to JPA, we will likely use ehcache anyway, so this isn't that bad, I guess.